# Как автоматизировать поиск картинок по штрихкодам?

Tags: php, алгоритм, штрихкод

Есть набор штрихкодов (цифры EAN-8,EAN-12, EAN-13), порядка 5 тысяч. Надо найти для них картинки.

Первое, что пришло в голову это заставить гугл поискать вот таким вот образом: https://www.google.com/m/products?q=5000174651164 собственно понятное дело в выдачу попали сайты с товарами. Собственно открыть страницу и найти там картинку - для меня не составит труда curl в этом помогает.

Допустим даже так, создал отдельную папку для каждого штрихкода и залил туда по 100 картинок с разных сайтов. Сохранил в БД их адрес и соответствие коду. Дальше как найти картинки скажем без водяных знаков? Вручную?

Вообще как определится, что картинка, соответствует содержанию? Может сравнивать их или что делать посоветуйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это глубоко ручная работа, если у тебя не будет специального каталога изображений этого поставщика с указанием кода.

На oDesk, work-zilla или freelance задай такую именно задачу. В результате тебе найдут и по папкам раскидают.

Comment: Вам конечно спасибо но все-таки задача не отдать другому а сделать самому.

Comment: "Вообще как определить, что картинка, соответствует содержанию?" - это может только человек.
Чтобы компьютеру алгоритмически определил наличие водянного знака, ему нужна база водянных знаков. Либо наличие ассоциативного мышления, чтобы понять, что изображение является коллажом обычного изображения и водянного знака.
Это ручная работа, если нет подготовленного каталога изображений.
На крайний случай - нужен комплекс из парсера картинок по твоему алгоритму и средства для визуального просмотра всех найденных картинок, чтобы человек мог чекбоксом отметить те, что ему подходят по смыслу и качеству

Comment: в общем то решил в полуавтоматичкеском(автомат. поиск, загрузка, ручной выбор подходящего материала после выгрузки) только тут пришлось не только штрихкод но и варианты названий поискать чтобы найти то, что надо.

Answer (score 2):

Вы на верном пути, но немного дорабатываем:

1.ссылка будет такая: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=5000174651164

2.используем парсер, и парсим страничку ищем ,"10019":
находим: ,"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcRy83MN5_ZZjcWulX-s4EpD99nNVlMeLxp-h-osgu_45zuzoik5t1_m-Z1XdBmE3GNy3EldwQ\u0026usqp\u003dCAc".....

3. теперь в этой строке производим замену символов

\u003d =

\u0026 &

4.получаем ссылку на рисунок, пользуемся.